# Rails 3.1 - How to edit and "proxy" HTTP request for Faye?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, http, proxy, request, faye

I have a Rails 3.1 app and have been using Faye for messaging.  I am wondering if it is possible to route all faye ('/faye') messages to the Faye server THROUGH my Rails app.  I have been experimenting with the below but without any luck and I haven't done much with Net::HTTP before.  Any help is appreciated, thanks.

config/route.rb
    match '/faye' => 'faye#default'

app/controllers/faye_controller.rb
    def default
      # I need code here to basically just edit and forward the request to my faye server
    end

I don't even need Rails to see the return path from Faye, just authenticate the client (or reject) and edit the request (add username to message) and let Faye do its thing.

I looked into Net::HTTP::Proxy but I only want to forward the packet.  I will be back in a couple hours so sorry for not being right here.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to configure your apache server to handle your faye forwarding.

```
<Proxy *> 
    Allow from all
</Proxy>

ProxyPass /somenamespace http://localhost:someport 
ProxyPassReverse /somenamespace http://localhost:someport
<Location /somenamespace>    
    Allow from all
</Location>
```

change someport to the port you are running your faye.